# Get the total number of specific key of an associative array

Tags: jquery, arrays, angularjs, firebase

Please how do i get the count of all "COLOR: RED" in this type of record?
Actually the the data is a firebase json object

```
myarray =
    {
      "CAR": {
        "COLOR": "RED",
        "ID": "41.203.65.171",
        "rating": 5
      },
      "BIKE": {
        "COLOR": "BLUE",
        "ID": "41.203.65.171",
        "rating": 8
      },
      "PLANE": {
        "COLOR": "RED",
        "ID": "41.203.65.171",
        "rating": 3
      },
```

i tried this:

```
var count = 0;
jQuery.each(myarray, function (key, value) {
    if (key == "COLOR" && value == "RED")) {
        counts[value]++;
    } else {
        counts = 0;
    }
});
```

the above has been wrong and thats whhy i need help,

i expect is someting like `red = 2`;

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Or are you looking for us to write the code for you?

Comment: Since there is no `COLOR: honda`, what on earth do you want? Can you include what you'd expect the result to be given the data  you have (which currently isn't valid anything)? And what you've tried so far?

Comment: You need to provide at least **some** code sample to show that you have actually worked on the issue or hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: Please post your code attempts, otherwise this just looks like you expect others to do your work and research

Comment: First - you don't have an array. You have an object. Second, you are resetting the count to `0` for every time that isn't "RED", clearly that's wrong.

Comment: now i have edited the question... please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we start with your object like this:

```
var data = {
  "CAR": {
    "COLOR": "RED",
    "ID": "41.203.65.171",
    "rating": 5
  },
  "BIKE": {
    "COLOR": "BLUE",
    "ID": "41.203.65.171",
    "rating": 8
  },
  "PLANE": {
    "COLOR": "RED",
    "ID": "41.203.65.171",
    "rating": 3
  }
};
```

Then you can count the number of objects that have COLOR=RED with something like this:

```
// First determine all the vehicletypes in an array
var vehicleTypes = Object.keys(data); // [ "CAR", "BIKE", "PLANE" ]

// Next, filter that array to only contain the RED vehicle types: [ "CAR", "PLANE" ]
var redVehicleTypes = vehicleTypes.filter(function(vehicleType) { 
  return data[vehicleType].COLOR == "RED" 
});

// Finally, count the number of elements in the array
var redVehicleCount = redVehicleTypes.length;
```

Note that this solution doesn't use jQuery, Firebase or Angular.

### Update

A solution that uses jQuery and is closer to your try:

```
var count = 0;
jQuery.each(data, function (key, value) {
    if (value["COLOR"] == "RED") {
        console.log("The "+key+" is red");
        count++;
    }
});
console.log(count);
```

The biggest change is in realizing the the `each` loops over vehicles, so you can simply check `value["COLOR"] == "RED"`.

Note that picking good variable names is **crucial** to being able to understand the code that you write. So in the snippet above I already replaced your `myArray` with `data`, since (as some commenters pointed out) your data structure is not an Array. I would also recommend changing the generic `key` and `value` to `vehicleType` and `vehicleData`:

```
var count = 0;
jQuery.each(data, function (vehicleType, vehicleData) {
    if (vehicleData.COLOR == "RED") {
        console.log("The "+vehicleType+" is red");
        count++;
    }
});
console.log(count);
```

Comment: THANKS so very much, i works fine just as i wanted. and i will also take note of my variable namings as described. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. If anything is not clear about either (without or with jQuery) approach, just ask. If it important that you understand them, so you have a better chance of getting to such a solution yourself next time.

Comment: In addition, you might have noticed that your question got some down votes and votes to be closed. Although I wasn't one of the voters, I do understand why people would vote that way on your original question. You were quick to edit your question into something more reasonable, but try to add some of the information you now added later in before hitting "Post Your Question" next time. :-)

Comment: Okay, i understand. I'm not really use to asking questions here, cause people here don't always seem friendly with their replies and votes, but you are just different... Thank you, I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a simple object that uses the colors as keys and has count as value

```
var colors ={};

jQuery.each(myarray, function (key, value) {
     var currColor = myarray[key].COLOR;
     /* add color as property if it doesn't already exist */
     if(!colors[ currColor ] ){
         colors[ currColor ] = 0;
      }
      /* increment count for the color */
      colors[ currColor ] ++;
});

console.log(colors)
// returns  {"RED": 2,"BLUE": 1}
alert(colors.RED) // 2
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0LkbadLy/)**</kbd>